# Joining two tables based on specific column value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, hue

I have two tables (Table 1 and Table 2) that I want to join them and create Table 3. The logic is the following:
**Table 1**
column1 | column2 |  column3
user1      |   ID1         |    name1
 user2      |   ID2         |    name2
 user3      |   ID3         |    name3
 user4      |   ID4         |    name4

**Table 2**
column1 | column2
user1      |   ACT1    
user1      |   ACT1    
user1      |   ACT1    
user1      |   ACT1    
user2      |   ACT2    
user3      |   ACT3    
user3      |   ACT3    
user3      |   ACT3    
user4      |   ACT4

### *I want the joined table to be this way:*

**Table 3**
column1 | column2  | column3
user1      |   ACT1     |   ID1    
user1      |   ACT1     |   ID1    
user1      |   ACT1     |   ID1    
user1      |   ACT1     |   ID1    
user2      |   ACT2     |   ID2    
user3      |   ACT3     |   ID3    
user3      |   ACT3     |   ID3    
user3      |   ACT3     |   ID3    
user4      |   ACT4     |   ID4

Basically, Table 3 is the same as Table 2. But, the corresponding ID for each user is fetched from Table1 and joined as a separate column. This process is repeated for all users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `JOIN` by `column1` column from `Table1` and `Table2`

```
select t2.*,t1.column2 as column3
from Table1 t1 
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.column1 = t2.column1
```

**[Results]**:

```
| column1 | column2 | column3 |
|---------|---------|---------|
|   user1 |    ACT1 |     ID1 |
|   user1 |    ACT1 |     ID1 |
|   user1 |    ACT1 |     ID1 |
|   user1 |    ACT1 |     ID1 |
|   user2 |    ACT2 |     ID2 |
|   user3 |    ACT3 |     ID3 |
|   user3 |    ACT3 |     ID3 |
|   user3 |    ACT3 |     ID3 |
|   user4 |    ACT4 |     ID4 |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00675e/2)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle link. It was very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

**You can have that answer even more simple:**

```
select  t1.column1, t2.column2, t1.column2 as column3 
from table1 as t1,  table2 as t2 
where t1.column1 = t2.column1
```

Answer (score 1):

seems you need  an inner join between table1 and table2 based  on column1

```
select  t1.column1, t2.column2, t1.column2 as column3 
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t1.column1 = t2.column1
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct. Except t1.column on the first line should change into t1.column2